# Haskell - Couldn't match expected type `(a2, a6)' with actual type `Pos'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In my code i have a data type Pos:

```
data Pos = Pos { col :: Char, row :: Int } deriving Show
```

and I have a function where I get 2 Pos instances and just want to return a string which describes a certain case:

```
whichCase :: Pos -> Pos -> String
whichCase start finish
    | snd start == snd finish = "horizontal"
    | fst start == fst finish = "vertical"
    | otherwise = "diagonal"
```

I get this Proble here:

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `(a2, a6)' with actual type `Pos'
    * In the first argument of `snd', namely `x'
      In the first argument of `(==)', namely `snd x'
      In the expression: snd x == snd y
    |
147 |     | snd x == snd y = "horizontal"
    |           ^
```

From what I understood from the Error message it says it expected x to be somthing different than Pos ? What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Unrelated, you may want to define a dedicated type like `data Case = Horizontal | Vertical | Diagonal` rather than relying on an implicitly defined subset of `String`. Types are cheap; don't be afraid of creating new ones to be precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fst` and `snd` have the purpose of extracting values from a *tuple*.

```
ghci> fst (37, "flub")
37
ghci> snd (True, -3.14)
-3.14
```

Now, your `Pos` type certainly is tuple-like (it is *isomorphic* to `(Char,Int)`), but that doesn't mean it *is* a tuple type. It's a *record type* instead, which means you can use the record field labels to do much the same thing:

```
ghci> col (Pos 'n' 5)
'n'
ghci> row (Pos 'n' 5)
5
```

So, you also should use those in your code.